# Auto Resizing / Expanding Column with Vertical-Scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

Is it possible to make a list out of widgets, like labels / buttons etc. in Y-Direction scrollable
but still let one column in X-Direction auto expand like in the code below?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x100")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure((0,2,3), minsize=100)
frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize=40)



coln = ["NO.", "Description","Name", "Button"]

for i in range(len(coln)):
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=coln[i], borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
    label.grid(column=i, row=0, sticky="NESW")

for i in range(20):
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=i+1, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    label.grid(column=0, row=i+1, sticky="NESW")

    label2 = tk.Label(frame, text="TEST_Descr.", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    label2.grid(column=1, row=i+1, sticky="NESW")

    label3 = tk.Label(frame, text="NAME", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    label3.grid(column=2, row=i+1, sticky="NESW")

    label4 = tk.Label(frame, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    label4.grid(column=3, row=i + 1, sticky="NESW")

    button = tk.Button(label4, text="OK!")
    button.pack(fill="x", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the common technique of adding the frame to a canvas for the scrolling. You can add a binding to the canvas so that when it resizes, you force the frame to be the width of the canvas minus the canvas border.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x100")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg=root.cget("background"))
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="pink")
canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", window=frame, tags=("inner_frame",))

def canvas_resize(event):
    border = int(canvas.cget("borderwidth"))
    event.widget.itemconfigure("inner_frame", width=event.width-border*2)

def frame_resize(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

canvas.bind("<Configure>", canvas_resize)
frame.bind("<Configure>", frame_resize)

frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure((0,2,3), minsize=100)
frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize=40)
coln = ["NO.", "Description","Name", "Button"]

for i in range(len(coln)):
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=coln[i], borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
    label.grid(column=i, row=0, sticky="NESW")

for i in range(20):
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=i+1, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    label.grid(column=0, row=i+1, sticky="NESW")

    label2 = tk.Label(frame, text="TEST_Descr.", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    label2.grid(column=1, row=i+1, sticky="NESW")

    label3 = tk.Label(frame, text="NAME", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    label3.grid(column=2, row=i+1, sticky="NESW")

    label4 = tk.Label(frame, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    label4.grid(column=3, row=i + 1, sticky="NESW")

    button = tk.Button(label4, text="OK!")
    button.pack(fill="x", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What if we comment out those frame.columnconfigure((0,2,3), minsize=100) and
frame.rowconfigure(0, minsize=40) it will not effect?

Comment: @toyotaSupra: why not try it and see?

Comment: I tried yet but it almost same. Thank